# In Win10 (w/o Homegroup) how can I share a folder with a specific user on my LAN, without them having an account on my PC?

Tags: windows-10, shared-folders

We don't have a Domain Controller. Homegroups are gone.  We're just a Workgroup with 5 Win10 1903 PCs (including mine).  Right now each co-worker has a local Win10 account on their PC.  I'd like to have a shared folder that is shared on the LAN but only accessible to 2 of my 4 co-workers.

In the "Choose people to share with" I can choose either EVERYONE or people with an account on my Win10 PC.  I cannot type in my_coworkers_name@HIS_COMPUTER_NAME or anything like that.  And I do not intend to give my coworkers my own login credentials for my own account.

Do I have to create an account on my own PC for them to use to access my folders?

Comment: Are you using Microsoft accounts by chance? You might be able to share stuff based on a Microsoft account (non-local)

Comment: Unfortunately users have to be able to authenticate if this is what you want. Yes, you have to create user accounts on your computer then Grant NTFS and Sharing permissions accordingly to those users. In addition, if you wish to avoid multiple password prompts the accounts you create on your computer should match the username / password they use on their computer. They could also save the credentials to eliminate the password prompts.

Answer (score 0):

The following method works reliably for me with Windows 10 machines.

1. In Advanced Network Sharing, make sure the Network Cards are set to Private (all machines) and that Network Discovery and File/Print Sharing are both enabled (all machines). Make sure Password are being used.
2. Make sure all computers are members of WORKGROUP.
3. If usernames on machines are different, make one main machine and enumerate usernames and passwords from the other machines on this main machine. Use of the same Microsoft Account can avoid this
4. Share the folders you want to the users you enumerated on the main machine.
5. If you wish to use computer names, add them to the local hosts files of the machines. Otherwise use IP addressing
6. Restart the computers and connect as above.

Comment: Would you clarify step 3. Each co-worker has a their own unique local Win10 account on their machine with their unique username and password.  What would need to be different to "avoid this"?

Comment: If usernames are different, the two usernames need to be added to your main machine. I think the users are different here but for a user with multiple machines and one Microsoft Account for all machines, no need to enumerate. I enumerate my own machines onto the main computer because all usernames are different.

Comment: Also the main machine needs to have the folders it is sharing in a neutral location. You cannot use USER folders as they are restricted and that is one reason why Homegroup was removed.  I use C:\Documents for this and share this folder